# Ensuring consistent mouse speeds when using different resolutions

Tags: 20.04

I frequently dock my 4k laptop to different monitors, sometimes HD, sometimes UHD etc and usually lower my built-in screen to match.

When I do this I notice the mouse, and more importantly the trackpad, speed varies and I need to re-set this on each dock.

Is there anyway to solve this?